# Excel VBA: hide/unhide columns in day-over-day tracker, skipping weekend columns

Tags: vba, excel

Simple in concept hard to implement. Been trying all day with no luck.

I have a day=over-day tracker. With each new day I would like to be able to run a macro that hides the previous day and unhides the current day. I have 10 days showing at a time (current day + 9 previous).

Through Googling, I was able to find some good code that functions as I describe except that it does not skip a column (which I would need to have occur if I want to essentially skip over weekend days in my tracker).

Thanks for your help.

```
sub whatever()
    dim i as long

    for i = 4 to 34

    if columns(i).hidden = false then
        bfirst = true
        columns(i).hidden = true
        columns(i + 10).hidden = false
    exit for
    end if
    next
end sub
```

Comment: Rather than looking for a code delivering exactly what you want (close to impossible), why don't you try to do it by your own? In this code, you have the basic functionalities you need: loop through columns, hidden/unhidden a column (and knowing whether a column is hidden). Understand what each bit does, change the attitude ("whatever" as the name of the sub does not denote too much interest) and remember that this is a site for programmers; if you are not a programmer (and don't want to become one), perhaps you should hire a programmer to write this for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your data has a row of Dates, you can indeed use `Weekday(Cells(r,c))` to determine if its a weekend, then use `Select Case` to hide/unhide columns.

The current can be retrieved by `Date()`.

Then you can set to codes in `Sub Workbook_Open()` in `ThisWorkbook` object. So when the file is opened, it runs the code so today and 9 previous days are not hidden.

EDIT: Add these 2 sub into "ThisWorkbook" object, change as per your sheet name, row and column. If you are to want 9 previous "Weekdays", then you will have to change the Case or use different approach to determine whether a column should be hidden or not. This is as far as I will go. Good luck!

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
    ShowTodayPlusPrevious
End Sub

Private Sub ShowTodayPlusPrevious()
    ' Assuming Row 1 contains the dates, stating from column 2
    Const DateRow As Long = 1
    Const PrevDays As Long = 9
    Dim oWS As Worksheet, lCol As Long, lLastCol As Long, bHide As Boolean

    Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Change this to the name of your sheet
    lLastCol = oWS.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
    For lCol = 2 To lLastCol
        bHide = True
        Select Case Date - oWS.Cells(DateRow, lCol).Value
            Case 0 To PrevDays
                If Weekday(oWS.Cells(DateRow, lCol).Value) <> vbSaturday And _
                    Weekday(oWS.Cells(DateRow, lCol).Value) <> vbSunday Then
                    bHide = False
                End If
        End Select
        oWS.Columns(lCol).Hidden = bHide
    Next
    Set oWS = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: so how would the final working version of this look like? i'm not good at visualizing VBA concepts until I see the result it laid out.